# Java timer random time each time between 2 values

Tags: java, swing, random, timer

I have a javax.swing.Timer which needs to run a method, after a random time between two int's.

After the object is made the object needs to keep 'running' (as in keep doing the thing int the timer).

what i have tried:

```
private int minimal = 30;
private int Max = 1000;
int randomTimeOutput; 
Random randomTime;
Timer timerRunAction

public Object()
{
    randomTime = new Random();
    randomTimeOutput =  (minimal +
        randomTime.nextInt(Max - minimal + 1));
    timerRunAction = new Timer(randomTimeOutput, this);
    timerRunAction.start();
}

private void doSomething()
{
    //Do something
}

private void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    dosomething();

}
```

*i have changed the names to make it more readable Object isn't the real class ofcause.*

But what happens is : the timer runs in a random times but it keeps running in the random time it runs the first time in.

So it isn't changing the time ,after each time it finished running.

How can i make it happen so it will run with a different time every time ?

Comment: Are you using `javax.swing.Timer` or `java.util.Timer`?

Comment: Where you using the Timer methods to change its delay? And why not use these methods?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels this is all i have, everything is working except it isn't changing the time.

Comment: Well your `actionPerformed()` is `private`. I think it needs to be `public` in order for your `Timer` to call the method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Problem

Your `Timer` is only being started and randomized once during your code, when the object is constructed. Every time the `Timer` sends an event to the `ActionListener`, nothing happens but calling `doSomething()`. Your timer delay is never re-randomized.

### Solution

Consider this code:

```
private int minimal = 30;
private int max = 1000;
int randomTimeOutput; 
Random randomTime;
Timer timerRunAction

public Object() {
    randomTime = new Random();
    randomTimeOutput =  (minimal + randomTime.nextInt(max - minimal + 1));
    timerRunAction = new Timer(randomTimeOutput, this);
    timerRunAction.start();
}

private void doSomething() {
    //Do something
}

private void updateTimer() {
    timerRunAction.stop();
    randomTimeOutput =  (minimal + randomTime.nextInt(max - minimal + 1));
    timerRunAction.setDelay(randomItemOutput);
    timerRunAction.restart();
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    dosomething();
    updateTimer();
}
```

I added the `updateTimer()` method that is called every time your timer sends an `ActionEvent` to your listener. What happens is the following:

1- The timer "goes off" and triggers an event. 
2- The code calls `doSomething()`. 
3- The code calls `updateTimer()`. 
4- `updateTimer()` first stops the timer, then picks a new random number and saves it to `randomTimeOutput`. 
5- `updateTimer()` sets the new delay of the timer and restarts it.

What this effectively does is every time the timer triggers an event, it's delay is randomized and it is restarted.

Hope this helped. Ask any questions you might have in the comments please.

Comment: is it neccesary to stop and start the delay, and what is the diffrence between setDelay and setInitialDelay

Comment: @SvenB I don't think it's necessary, but I did it anyway and it doesn't hurt. And according to the JavaDoc [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html). `setInitialDelay()` allows you to set the time after starting before the first event, then `setDelay()` lets you set the time for every subsequent event.

Answer (score 3):

You should call `setDelay(...)` on your timer in its actionPerformed when you want to change its delay time. This is all easily findable in the Timer's API which I suggest that you check out.

---

Regarding your new edit:

?`newRandom()`??

- Don't stop the Timer
- Choose a reasonable random number for your next time delay. Sometimes this can be as simple as creating an array or ArrayList of delays and randomly selecting one of them.
- Else you could use a random.nextInt(A + B) - B + 1 to get a random number between A and B.

Comment: and then set the first parameter to 0 ?

Comment: @SvenB: no, to a random number if desired.